# cycle through list to match value with multiple matches possible

Tags: r

I am interested in cycling through a list of diagnosis codes and populating a new variable with a previously calculated risk score if the value matches, and if there are multiple matches populate the new variable with the highest risk score.

I am hoping to take the long form of the original data set and for each ID match the proc number with the highest risk score and store both the proc number and risk score in separate variables.

I have some experience using if loops to do similar things in wide data, but cannot figure out how to do it this way. I have no experience matching and then storing the highest value, so don't even know where to start with this.

Data to see what I am getting at:

Here is the data from for the diagnosis codes

```
dz <-c("disease_1", "disease_2", "disease_3", "disease_4")
code <-c(124, 546, 890, 898)
risk_score <-c(10, 122, 45, 98)
df <-data.frame(dz, code, risk_score)
```

And the simulated data set I am interested in

```
 id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
 proc <-c(244,546,234,345,890,123,434,634,233,345,124,234,634,546,789,890,567,124)
 proc<-as.character(proc)
 data<-data.frame(id, proc)
```

so what I want to achieve is something like this

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
code_match<-c(546,890,124,546,890)
highest_risk_score <-c(122,45,10,122,45)
output_df<-data.frame(id, code_match, highest_risk_score)
```

with this output

```
  id code_match highest_risk_score
1  1        546                122
2  2        890                 45
3  3        124                 10
4  4        546                122
5  5        890                 45
```

with id being the identifier, the code_match being the code with the highest risk score, and the highest_risk_score being the value of the risk score (the highest value for that id).

Comment: you are correct

Comment: It's true, because I am not interested in those codes. the data I am working with will have multiple codes per ID that I have no interest in.

Comment: correct, because I don't know how to do it. I thought an example of the output I am interested in would illustrate what I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: Not sure why all the `-1`s today but I ticked it back to 0. This had code + data and was reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll use an alternate way of creating those data frames:

```
data.frame(
  dz = c("disease_1", "disease_2", "disease_3", "disease_4"),
  code = as.character(c(124, 546, 890, 898)),
  risk_score = c(10, 122, 45, 98),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> df

data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
  proc = as.character(c(244, 546, 234, 345, 890, 123, 434, 634, 233, 345, 124, 234, 634, 546, 789, 890, 567, 124)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> data
```

Here's one way (in `tidyverse` and base R) to do this:

#### 57 compiled  dependency `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

filter(data, proc %in% df$code) %>%
  left_join(df, by=c("proc"="code")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  top_n(1) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(id, code_match = proc, highest_risk_score = risk_score)
## # A tibble: 4 x 3
## # Groups:   id [4]
##      id code_match highest_risk_score
##   <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>
## 1    1. 546                      122.
## 2    2. 890                       45.
## 3    4. 546                      122.
## 4    5. 890                       45.
```

#### 0  (ok, 1 — `stats` — which comes along for the ride with base R) Base R solution

```
tmp <- merge(data[with(data, proc %in% df$code),], df, by.x = "proc", by.y = "code")

do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(
    split(tmp, tmp$id),
    function(x) {
      x[which.max(x$risk_score),]
    }
  )
)[,-3] -> tmp

setNames(tmp[,c(2,1,3)], c("id", "code_match", "highest_risk_score"))
##   id code_match highest_risk_score
## 1  1        546                122
## 2  2        890                 45
## 4  4        546                122
## 5  5        890                 45
```

You've not mentioned how to handle not-matches so this just ignores them.

Comment: This works great and introduced me to top_n(), thanks. However, I ran into an issue where some IDs have multiple instances because the id had a the same code with risk listed more than once. How can I select out just one instance after the last line in the `tidyverse` method code?

Comment: See the update. A `slice(1)` should work. (and I forgot an `ungroup()` at the end which you should def add.